# ¿ Controlador por entidad?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, mvc, diseño, patrones-de-diseño

Actualmente busco como mejorar mi desarrollo, corrigiendo lo que estoy realizando mal.

Me gustaría saber, al aplicar el patrón DAO y MVC, tengo entendido que se debe crear una entidad que representa cada tabla en la base de datos, por lo cual, tendría una clase cuyos atributos serían los campos de la tabla en la base de datos, este sería el conocido VO (Value Object), de igual forma debo tener un DAO por cada VO (o por cada tabla en la base de datos, como se quiera ver), que sería el encargado de realizar las consultas a la BD, lo anterior estaría inmerso en el Modelo. (Si tengo algún concepto mal aplicado por favor hacérmelo saber)

Ahora bien, si busco aplicar de forma correcta los patrones, **¿debería tener un controlador por cada entidad?** (Osea, por cada ClaseVO) Siendo la conexión de todas las partes de la siguiente forma: Vista: En el botón "Registrar" invoco al Controlador, el Controlador llama al DAO que realiza las operaciones en la BD.

Comment: Siento decirte que las preguntas donde puede haber varias opiniones, o cuya solución es subjetiva, no son el modelo esperado en stackoverflow. Echa un ojo. Es posible q te respondan pero mejor que leas esto y trates de acotar tu pregunta más específicamente https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Te agradezco la aclaración, cuando dices que la respuesta puede ser subjetiva significa que tiene varias multiples soluciones y todas serian correctas, mi pregunta en especifico es: ¿ Es correcto en MVC tener un Controlador por cada VO (Value Object) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre tu comentario, trataré de complementar dando mas una solución personal:

Trabajando en MVC:

A las interfaces gráficas, ya sea html o interfaz de aplicación  con formulario y botones las llamaré genéricamente "pantallas".

Las "pantallas" siempre tienen un componente íntimamente relacionado, un "controlador de pantalla" propio para recibir los eventos y acciones realizados.

En este "controlador de pantalla" debes tener la lógica mínima para darle vida a la pantalla relacionada. Por ejemplo, cuando se realizan eventos sobre las pantallas, allí en el controlador debe existir la lógica mínima detectando que tipo de evento se ejecuto, que información debe preparar y almacenar en DTO y luego invocar el CONTROLADOR pasándole los parámetros que se han preparado. Si es en dirección contraria, que se recibe información del controlador para mostrar en la vista, el "controlador de pantalla" realiza el procesamiento mínimo para, por ejemplo, dividir los paquetes de información que le entregan (por ejemplo, filtrar ciertos DTO que mostrará en un listado de nombres, filtrar cuales mostrará en un listado de productos) y deja todo listo para que las pantallas lo muestren correctamente sin "pensar de ninguna forma."

Ahora bien, complementé la capa vista así:

VISTA

Pantalla

Controlador de Pantalla

Ahora el CONTROLADOR:

El controlador contiene funciones o métodos (java) con un nombre específico de la labor que ejecuta... por ejemplo, puede existir dos funciones:
--- registrarInformacionYAplicarSorteo(...parametros...)
--- ignorarPersonaYLlamarALaPolicia(...parametros...)
Según el que se llame, realizará una LÓGICA DE NEGOCIO DIFERENTE.

En el controlador se toma la información que se recibe de la vista, lee puntualmente las propiedades del DTO, determina que hacer con la información (por ejemplo, a partir del teléfono llamar a la policia, según la edad ver si es legal que participe en una lotería) y prepara, de nuevo los DTO para enviarlos a la capa MODELO para ser guardados, actualizados, etc.

La capa MODELO recibirá aquellas unidades de información DTO, cuando le invoquen sus funciones y métodos, y según la función llamada, realizará una función puntual sin realizar ningún tipo de procesamiento mayor. Por ejemplo:

--- guardarInformacionPersonal()

--- guardarInformacionAdicionalPersonal()

---

Posdata:

Ya en el mundo del desarrollo de aplicaciones empresariales Java EE, se trabaja con la "Arquitectura por Capas", te dejo el siguiente enlace [Layered Architecture](https://dzone.com/articles/layered-architecture-is-good)

Por ejemplo en JSF de Java EE, las "pantallas" tienen su "controlador de pantalla" íntimamente relacionado que se llama Backing Bean (también llamado Managed Bean)

Lo que te queda, es ponerte a desarrollar proyectos de ejemplo y tener siempre en mente que cada capa, cada componente, cada cosa, cumpla una función en específico y en un solo lugar... que desde la vista nunca se llame directamente a las funciones-métodos del modelo, que en la vista no se realicen cálculos, etc.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedo decirte que es correcto crear un VO y un DAO por cada tabla en la base de datos.

Mencionas en tu mensaje el concepto de Entidad, que siento está mas relacionado con el tema de los ORM (tipo Hibernate, JPA...) pero eso ya es un tema de otro nivel aparte. Te recomiendo consultar sobre los DTO (Data Transfer Object).

la capa MODELO la tienes compuesta con los DAO y VO.

La capa del controlador, como su nombre indica, gestiona que las acciones realizadas en la vista (por ejemplo, introducir datos, presionar botones) se procesen y generen cambios de datos en el Modelo según la "lógica de negocio" (función de tu aplicativo). También que, a partir de los datos ya almacenados en la capa MODELO se procesen (realizar cálculos adecuados) de una forma adecuada para entregárselos a la capa VISTA y que solo tenga que presentarlos de una forma adecuada (y por qué no, bonita).

La capa de la VISTA si está mas pensada solo para presentar la información, debe ser lo mas "bruta" posible, que en ella no se procese ningún tipo de información con una lógica de negocio. A lo mucho sería admisible que en esta capa se hagan por ejemplo conversiones de datos (por ejemplo, de valores numéricos a cadenas de texto si es que los resultados traídos de otras capas no pueden venir preparados como String).

Por cierto, en la capa MODELO no se debe realizar procesamiento o cálculos elaborados. La razón de ser de esta capa es solo facilitar los accesos (para consultar, modificar, insertar o borrar datos) a un gestor de bases de datos para cargar, modificar y demás los datos respaldados en ella.

Perdona dejar para el final la respuesta a la pregunta principal: No, no es necesario crear un controlador por cada DAO-VO-Tabla_De_BD. El controlador debe tener correspondencia de uno por funcionalidad diría yo, y siendo así, también 1 vista por funcionalidad (unidad mínima que realiza una labor, por ejemplo una funcionalidad donde se llena un formulario de inscripción a una universidad)

Estas son respuestas pensadas al nivel de tu pregunta. En un futuro cuando avances mas en la ciencia y abordes por ejemplo el mundo Java EE de Aplicaciones Empresariales verás que la respuesta que te doy tiene otras variaciones y complementaciones interesantes.

Un saludo.

Comment: No te preocupes, al contrario, gracias por aclararme algunas ideas, cuando mencione sobre VO me referia en realidad a los DTO que son los que representan las tablas. Cuando hablas de que la VISTA debe ser lo mas "bruta posible", muy posiblemente yo este violando este concepto por dos motivos: 1- En el código del botón instancio al Controlador. 2- Instancio el DTO al que le voy pasando los datos por medios de los setter, para posteriormente pasar ese objeto como parámetro al Controlador. Si el MODELO no debe ser para realizar procesamientos o calculos elaborados, donde debería realizaros ?