# ¿ Como implementar MVC en Java?

Tags: java, mvc, diseño, patrones-de-diseño, arquitectura

Estoy estudiando acerca de MVC, sin embargo tengo dudas acerca de su correcta implementacion ya que veo en todas partes que se realiza de forma diferente.

Ahora, lo que yo hago es lo siguiente:

1- Creo los DTO que representan mis tablas en la BD.

2- Creo los DAO correspondiente por cada DTO.

**3- Creo un Controlador por cada DTO **(No se si esto correcto)**

4- Creo la Vista (Usando Window Builder en NetBeans).

**5- En el código del Botón instancio el DTO y por medio de los setters modifico sus atributos. (No se si esto sea correcto)**

6- Invoco al Controlador, al cual le paso como parametros el objeto DTO.

En los ejercicios que he visto observo que la Vista no se llama al Controlador, su no que desde el Controlador se llama a la Vista.

Un fragmento de mi aplicación:

**MODELO:** EmpleadoDTO:

```
package Modelo;
/**
 *
 * @author Julian Lopez
 */
public class Empleado {

    private int empleadoId;
    private String empleadoNombre;
    private String empleadoApellido;
    private String empleadoContacto;


    public Empleado(int empleadoId, String empleadoNombre, String empleadoApellido, String empleadoContacto) {
        this.empleadoId = empleadoId;
        this.empleadoNombre = empleadoNombre;
        this.empleadoApellido = empleadoApellido;
        this.empleadoContacto = empleadoContacto;

    }

    public Empleado() {
        this.empleadoId = 0;
        this.empleadoNombre = "";
        this.empleadoApellido = "";
        this.empleadoContacto = "";
    }

    public int getEmpleadoId() {
        return empleadoId;
    }

    public void setEmpleadoId(int empleadoId) {
        this.empleadoId = empleadoId;
    }

    public String getEmpleadoNombre() {
        return empleadoNombre;
    }

    public void setEmpleadoNombre(String empleadoNombre) {
        this.empleadoNombre = empleadoNombre;
    }

    public String getEmpleadoApellido() {
        return empleadoApellido;
    }

    public void setEmpleadoApellido(String empleadoApellido) {
        this.empleadoApellido = empleadoApellido;
    }

    public String getEmpleadoContacto() {
        return empleadoContacto;
    }

    public void setEmpleadoContacto(String empleadoContacto) {
        this.empleadoContacto = empleadoContacto;
    }

}
```

**MODELO:** EmpleadoDAO

```
public class EmpleadoDAO {
    public ArrayList<Empleado> listarEmpleado(int empleadoId) {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement prepared = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        ArrayList<Empleado> listado = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            con = Conexion.getConection();
            String selectSQL = "";

            if (empleadoId == 0) {
                selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tb_empleado";
            } else {
                selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tb_empleado WHERE Empleado_ID = ?";
            }
            prepared = con.prepareStatement(selectSQL);

            if (empleadoId != 0) {
                prepared.setInt(1, empleadoId);
            }

            result = prepared.executeQuery();
            Empleado empleado = null;

            while (result.next()) {
                empleado = new Empleado();
                empleado.setEmpleadoId(result.getInt("Empleado_ID"));
                empleado.setEmpleadoNombre(result.getString("Empleado_Nombre"));
                empleado.setEmpleadoApellido(result.getString("Empleado_Apellido"));
                empleado.setEmpleadoContacto(result.getString("Empleado_Contacto"));
                listado.add(empleado);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Código : "
                    + ex.getErrorCode() + "\nError :" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return listado;
    }

    public int grabarEmpleado(Empleado empleado) {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement prepared = null;
        int resultado = 0;

        try {
            con = Conexion.getConection();
            String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO tb_empleado VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            prepared = con.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
            prepared.setInt(1, empleado.getEmpleadoId());
            prepared.setString(2, empleado.getEmpleadoNombre());
            prepared.setString(3, empleado.getEmpleadoApellido());
            prepared.setString(4, empleado.getEmpleadoContacto());
            resultado = prepared.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Código : "
                    + ex.getErrorCode() + "\nError :" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

**CONTROLADOR**: ControladorEmpleado:

```
public class ControladorEmpleado {
    public static ArrayList<Empleado> listarEmpleado(int empleadoId) {
        ArrayList<Empleado> listaEmpleado; //= new ArrayList<>();
        EmpleadoDAO empleadoDAO = new EmpleadoDAO();
        listaEmpleado = empleadoDAO.listarEmpleado(empleadoId);
        return listaEmpleado;

    }

    public static int grabarEmpleado(Empleado empleado) {
        EmpleadoDAO empleadoDAO = new EmpleadoDAO();
        int resultado = empleadoDAO.grabarEmpleado(empleado);
        return resultado;
    }
```

**VISTA:** AgregarEmpleado (Aquí instancio al EmpleadoDTO y modifico sus atributos por medio de los setter, posteriormente invoco al Controlador correspondiente y le paso el objeto EmpleadoDTO como parámetro ¿ Es correcto que llame al EmpleadoDTO siendo este parte del MODELO ?

```
private void btnGrabarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if (txtEmpleadoID.getText().equals("") || txtEmpleadoNombre.getText().equals("")
                || txtEmpleadoApellido.getText().equals("") || txtEmpleadoContacto.getText().equals("")
                || txtEmpleadoDireccion.getText().equals("") || txtEmpleadoSalario.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor diligencie todos los datos", "Falta Informacion", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {

            Empleado miEmpleado = new Empleado();
            CargoEmpleado cargosEmpleado = new CargoEmpleado();

            cargosEmpleado = (CargoEmpleado) cboCargo.getSelectedItem();

            int empleadoId = Integer.parseInt(txtEmpleadoID.getText());
            String empleadoNombre = txtEmpleadoNombre.getText();
            String empleadoApellido = txtEmpleadoApellido.getText();
            String empleadoContacto = txtEmpleadoContacto.getText();
            String empleadoDireccion = txtEmpleadoDireccion.getText();
            int empleadoSalario = Integer.parseInt(txtEmpleadoSalario.getText());

            miEmpleado.setEmpleadoId(empleadoId);
            miEmpleado.setEmpleadoNombre(empleadoNombre);
            miEmpleado.setEmpleadoApellido(empleadoApellido);
            miEmpleado.setEmpleadoContacto(empleadoContacto);

            int resultado = ControladorEmpleado.grabarEmpleado(miEmpleado);

            if (resultado == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nuevo empleado registrado.");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo realizar el registro.", "Oopps... ", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

        }
    }
```

PD: Soy consciente que siendo un poco mas exigente, las validaciones de los campos debería haberla hecho en una Clase aparte y no como la tengo aquí, donde la valido en el código del botón. No uso ningún Framework en especifico.

Comment: en esta otra pregunta [¿ Controlador por entidad?
](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/133977/controlador-por-entidad) describo un poco sobre MVC. Tal vez te sea de ayuda.